# Google pubsub acknowledgement from a different client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Here is what I need to accomplish:

1. Get some messages in System 1 using a Pull Subscription.
2. Send each message along with acknowledgement id to System 2
3. Send acknowledgement to the subscription from that System 2.

So, basically I will create a new Pubsub client and send acknowledgement. How can I make this request?

Comment: Can you please phrase this as a question? Are you having trouble with something specific regarding passing the ack ID to a different client?

Comment: yes, that was the problem. I figured out the mistake. I was not invoking execute() . I will close the issue

Answer (score 0):

I added the execute() method to the acknowledgment operation:

```
            client.projects().subscriptions()
                    .acknowledge(getFullSubscriptionsName(config), acknowledgeRequest)
                    .execute();
```

The method execute() was not being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

To complement your answer, I just realized that your client is a Pubsub java class and the method execute() belongs to an instance of Acknowledge.

I found a [full example that pulls messages](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/blob/master/cmdline-pull/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/client/demos/cli/SubscriptionMethods.java) from Pubsub. In fact, the pullMessages() method in such example has the sentence you mentioned. Digging into the java framework, this link mentions [how the method exetute() is used](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/pubsub/Pubsub.Projects.Subscriptions.Acknowledge.html#Acknowledge-java.lang.String-com.google.api.services.pubsub.model.AcknowledgeRequest-).